# org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in Android Studio with phpserver

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli

I have this as JavaCode:

```
private void loginUser(){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            launchHomeScreen();
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Welcome back " + username,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return params;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

And as the php code at my server this code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("censored", "censored", "censored", "censored");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colUsername, $colPassword);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

And get the following Error:

org.json.JSONException: Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

SO what is wrong with my code?

**LOGCAT DURING THIS ACTION:**

```
03-29 18:26:10.069 1255-1420/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xac403b40) throttle end: throttle time(10)
03-29 18:26:10.080 1255-1420/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xac403b40) throttle end: throttle time(10)
03-29 18:26:10.100 2811-3922/com.fun.goD/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
03-29 18:26:10.113 1249-1291/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.215 1249-1291/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.220 1249-1291/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.231 2811-2881/com.fun.goE/EGL_emulation: tid 2881: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-29 18:26:10.231 2811-2881/com.fun.livster W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb20b0c60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-29 18:26:10.745 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.fun.livster.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:120)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.fun.livster.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:116)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
03-29 18:26:10.746 2811-2811/com.fun.goW/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
03-29 18:26:10.784 1519-1991/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 2018:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 906): empty #17
03-29 18:26:10.792 1519-2000/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@86ca045 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@d693449
03-29 18:26:10.821 1519-1626/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 2018
03-29 18:26:10.828 1249-1905/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.831 1249-1289/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.834 1249-1289/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-29 18:26:10.843 2811-2881/com.fun.livster E/EGL_emulation: tid 2881: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-29 18:26:10.843 2811-2881/com.fun.livster W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb20b0ca0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-29 18:26:10.959 1519-1540/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.fun.go/com.fun.livster.LoginActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
03-29 18:26:13.777 2811-2811/com.fun.livster W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-29 18:26:14.827 1519-1540/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Toast) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
03-29 18:26:20.770 1519-1991/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 3034:com.android.gallery3d/u0a40 (adj 906): empty #17
03-29 18:26:20.831 1519-1530/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3034
```

The complete response is:

```
<br /> <b> Warning</b>: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in <b>/home/u3462344/public_html/login.php<b/> on line <b>11</b><br /> {"success":false}
```

Comment: your backend responds with wrong data. It sends back some HTML instead of JSUN

Comment: @VladMatvienko  So the problem is in my php... How the Code in my login.php should looks like?

Comment: Don't know. It looks OK for me now. Possibly you are using wrong URL, or your server is misconfigured. Try doing same thing through web browser, or some google chrome plugin (Postman?), and see what you get in response.

Comment: so, that's not an android issue, that's a php issue. You are not using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` as expected. I suggest you read the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or your JSON has the wrong format or your JSON from your back is empty, you should show the result from your server.

In your PHP code return the JSON with HTML, you need and header type, add this code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

And your final code should look like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("censored", "censored", "censored", "censored");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colUsername, $colPassword);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: So I updated my php code a little bit.[Look above] The result from response is: "<br /> <b> Warning</b>: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in <b>/home/u3462344/public_html/login.php<b/> on line <b>11</b><br /> {"success":false} What to do?

Comment: Try to catch all the message in android, if you receive all that html in android that´s the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but how to do this?

Comment: After this line `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);` you put this `Log.d("JSONR", jsonResponse.toString());` and in your log you can see your json in console when your are debugging.

Comment: I only see the thing I posted in my Qustion under "EDIT:"

Comment: Ok, you posted the Android Monitor, so try again and show the log,  if you have response in your android you will can see the responso in monitor so copy this code, run and show me the response pls`JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);Log.d("JSONR", jsonResponse.toString());System.out.println("JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse.toString());` In android monitor you can find specific word in your log, there look for JSON

Comment: See in my Qestion. Is that what you need? :)

Comment: Yes, I see that your are trying to parse "br" to JSON but that's part of HTML, you have yo fix your php to return only json

Comment: I add in my answer how to return only json in php, try adding that and tell me if it works

Comment: Guerra Sorry for this Qestion, but how to fix it? How the code php-code should looks like?

Comment: Look my answer, I posted  the php code

Answer (score 2):

check the php file.Maybe you just wrong on the number of parameters in sql.

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM tblgowninfo WHERE type = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss", $type2);

The "ss" is wrong since you only have 1 string parameter.Should be "s"